# How to create a nested template to deploy resources to subscriptions in different Azure AD Tenants?

Tags: azure, multi-tenant, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create a nested ARM-template to deploy resources to subscriptions in different Azure AD tenants.

For guidance I used this site: [Deploy Azure resources to more than one subscription or resource group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-cross-resource-group-deployment)

There it says *"If the specified subscription exists in a different Azure Active Directory tenant, you must add guest users from another directory."* which leads me to believe that this should be possible.

I have an account in Tenant A (6f16...) which is Azure AD Global Administrator and Contributor to the CSP Subscription (04c5...) which is assigned to Tenant A.

I have added this account in Tenant B (1ffc...) as "New guest user" and assigned him as Contributor to the Pay-As-You-Go Subscription (ebda...) and also made him Global Administrator in the Azure AD from Tenant B.

To keep it simple I used the first example template on the site which should deploy two storage accounts in two different resource groups and two different subscriptions.

In the parameters file I indicated for 'secondSubscriptionID' the subscription ID (ebda...) assigned to Tenant B (1ffc...) and an existing resource group in that subscription for 'secondResourceGroup':

```
      ...
      "secondResourceGroup": {
        "value": "existing-resource-group-in-Ten-B" },
      "secondSubscriptionID": {
        "value": "ebda..." },
      ...
```

I am trying to deploy it through Azure CLI:

```
az login -u <emailaddress> -p <pw>
az account set --subscription 04c5...
az group deployment create --resource-group "existing-resource-group-in-Ten-A" `
--template-file stor.temp.json --parameters @stor.para.json
```

I receive this error message:

```
Azure Error: CrossTenantDeploymentNotPermitted
Message: The template deployment tries to deploy resources to subscription 'ebda...'. 
However, the current tenant '6f16...' is not authorized to 
deploy resources to that subscription. 
Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.
```

I received the same error message in the Azure Portal or with PowerShell. I also tried it with with other tenants/subscriptions.

Am I missing some permissions? Is this even supported?

Is there a better way to deploy resources to multiple tenants than this one?

Answer (score 1):

You login into tenant A and set subscription to `0c45` to tenant A but 
you reference subscription `ebda` in tenant B in your ARM Templates.

You have to login and set Tenant B / subscription ebda.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs-cli/issues/667

```
az login --username <myEmailAddress> -t <tenantIDofTenantB>
az account set --subscription <TenantBSubscriptionId>
az group deployment create ......
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But if I login to tenant B (1ffc) with subscription B (ebda) and try to deploy like this:

 az group deployment create --resource-group <existing-resource-group-in-tenant-A>  
I get this error: ```Azure Error: ResourceGroupNotFound
Message: Resource group '...' could not be found.``` And if i indicate an existing resource group in tenant B than I have both storage accounts deployed to tenant B.

Comment: I think now I get the problem. You can only deploy resources to multiple subscriptions / resource groups within the same tenant. Perhaps the docs should have specified that explicitly.

Comment: If it is like you say, then the documentation really should be updated. Thank you!

Comment: I've encountered the problem before and revisited after seeing @RobinS 's question. I've opened the following issue on the document and will hopefully get an answer.  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34249